# Setting an array of objects to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

Ok, so I have this JSON:

```
{"Status":"OK!","ListaPermessi":
[{"IdPermesso":10,"Nome":"WIND_PARAMS"},
 {"IdPermesso":11,"Nome":"ADMIN_SERVER"},
 {"IdPermesso":21,"Nome":"REC"},
 {"IdPermesso":22,"Nome":"REC_DIST"},
 {"IdPermesso":23,"Nome":"REC_DIST_CR"}
]}
```

My code is:

```
var parsedResult = JSON.parse(result); // where result is the above JSON
if (parsedResult.Status === "OK!") {
    // Set sessionStorage vars
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // localStorage & sessionStorage support!

        sessionStorage.setItem("ListaPermessi", parsedResult.ListaPermessi);
    }
    else {
        // Sorry! No web storage support :(
    }
}
```

But... this is not working properly! After the assignment, the sessionStorage seen from Firebug looks like this:

**sessionStorage**:

- ListaPermessi = "*[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]*"

What is the proper way to assign an array of objects to a **sessionStorage** variable from javascript?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to turn it back into a JSON string. You can do that with the [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("ListaPermessi", JSON.stringify(parsedResult.ListaPermessi));
```

The reason for this is that web storage can only store strings, and the default `toString` method of `Object` returns, as you've now seen, "[object Object]".

---

Side note: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, not a function, so there's no need for the parentheses:

```
if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") { //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But, still not working! I've tried it and it parses the list as a string, not as an array of objects.

Comment: @CosminT. - What do you mean? What is the result of `JSON.stringify(parsedResult.ListaPermessi)`?

Comment: `"[{"IdPermesso":10,"Nome":"WIND_PARAMS"}, {"IdPermesso":11,"Nome":"ADMIN_SERVER"},
 {"IdPermesso":21,"Nome":"REC"},
 {"IdPermesso":22,"Nome":"REC_DIST"},
 {"IdPermesso":23,"Nome":"REC_DIST_CR"}
]"`. as a string, between ""

Comment: @CosminT. - That's what you should get. You can only store strings in web storage. You can call `JSON.parse` on that value to convert it back into an actual JS data structure.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! So it cannot have "an array structure". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CosminT. - You're welcome, glad I could help :) Just remember to always call `JSON.stringify` when storing, and `JSON.parse` when retrieving data to/from web storage.