# Share array of objects between two pages

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have an array of objects on a page that I want to have on another page in electron. Both pages have there own javascript file and there is one function.js
file.

**file1.js**

```
const { createArray, getArray } = require ('./function')

window.onload = () => {
    createArray()
    sessionStorage.setItem("Array", getArray)
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("Array")   //[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
    console.log(getArray) // [{"1": 10}, {"2": 11}, {"3": 12}]
}
```

By the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq) of Electron getting variables from one page to the other is best done via the HTML 5 API's.

But I'm not able to store an array of object in a sessionStorage. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562778/setting-an-array-of-objects-to-sessionstorage) that is perfectly normale. The solution used here is to stringify. But that is a rather expensive process that I would like to avoid.

Does anybody have any idea how best to share an array of objects between two pages?

Comment: I don't think other solutions would be "less expensive" unless we're talking like huge arrays here. In that case a server side database would probably be preferred. With only 3 objects inside the array, I would opt for localStorange or the IPC system your link to the documentation mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the array in your background script and provide it to the BrowserWindows using the messaging API: [Link](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem by simply re use `getArray` from the other page, so just re import it.

`const { createArray, getArray } = require ('./function')`

Otherwise you need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` using `sessionStorage`, example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Array", JSON.stringify(getArray));
const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("Array"))
```

Or you can use IPC to Set the Global's Value.

As side note:
Use a more descriptive name instead of "Array" for `sessionStorage`